# KPIs in Docplex?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I want to add a KPI to calculate the percentage of occupancy of vehicles: the total travel time of occupied arcs (where the capacity of a vehicle is non-zero) over the total travel time.

How can I represent that using three variables: the $x_{ij}$ variable equal to $1$ if there is an arc between $i$ and $j$, the $q_i$ the capacity of vehicle after serving vertex $i$ and the $b_i$ the starting time of service for vertex $i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[kpi syntax example](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zookpi.py) in [docplex](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')

nbbus=nbbus30+nbbus40
mdl.add_kpi(nbbus,"nbbus")
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve(log_output=True,)

mdl.export("c:\\temp\\buses.lp")

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

for k in mdl.iter_kpis():
    print(k," = ",k.solution_value)
```